# jQuery: Stacking divs and cycling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there any plugin out there that will let me place divs on top of one another and allow me to cycle through them? Something like this:

```
  --------------
         DIV 2  |
--------------  |
      DIV 1   | |
              | |
              |
              |
              |
              |
```

Answer (score 2):

[JQuery Cycle Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm looking for something that can actually show all the divs in the background as well. Something like the figure I've drawn (cycling through a set of cards?). I am not sure if the cycle plugin can do this. I think this has to do with css and some matrix transformations but I was curious if someone already made a plugin for this.